# npm parse for Javascript doesn't retrieve all the fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

i'm using the npm package `parse/node` to read a parse server data.
I've configured my module as follows :

```
const Parse = require('parse/node')
Parse.serverURL = app.config.parse.url
Parse.initialize(app.config.parse.appId, null, app.config.parse.masterKey)
```

using the following code, the Parse server sends me back an object containing only the field 'id'

```
const options = {useMasterKey: true, masterKey: app.config.parse.masterKey}
let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
query.equalTo('objectId', 'zzo2sAxJbJ')
let res = await query.find(options)
console.log('Res :', res)
```

the result is the following :

`Res : [ ParseObjectSubclass { className: '_User', _objCount: 0, id: 'zzo2sAxJbJ' } ]`

any idea on how i can retrieve all the data for a User ?
and not only the id....

Answer (score 0):

The fields are there, just not when you print it that way. You can easily see this by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(res))`

Note that the recommended way to access the fields of a Parse object is via the `get` function.

i.e. `console.log("user name: " + res[0].get("name"));`

Comment: thanks, but that's what i've tried :/ but i always get the same result... anyway i decided to use the Rest API instead, which has proven to be more reliable